# Date conversion when sending date in JBossWs web service

Tags: java, web-services, date

I have small test setup where my server (host a webservice) is in BST timezone and the Client (Simple java based web service client) in EDT.
When Date objects (part of bigger complex objects) are sent from Client to Server or vice versa, the dates are being adjusted. For example

Thu Aug 9 23:24:31 BST 2012 on Server would be seen as Thu Aug  9 18:24:37 EDT 2012 at the Client.
I understand this is correct and fine.

In the application that I have mentioned, client and server both are unaware of the opposite sides timezone. So without the respective timezone information, how can I preserve the Time value.

i.e. When Aug 9 23:24:31 2012 is transmitted from server, client should also get Aug 9 23:24:31 2012 as the value.

I hope I am making sense.

Comment: What do you want to see at the client? "Thu Aug 9 23:24:31 BST 2012"? "Thu Aug 9 23:24:31 EDT 2012"? Something else?

Comment: Date information through webservices typically transmit the data in UTC, it is up to the client to determine how they want it display. By default of course it uses the system locale. If you want to force it, you have to code it in the client to use specific locale.

Comment: @DannyLagrouw Update the question text to clarify.

Comment: @SalmanA.Kagzi, Simplest way is to send the date as `String` instead of `Date`. In your web service, convert the Date to String and send that to clients.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this exact same problem about a month ago. It drove me crazy, because it would roll the date over because of the UTC time. The clients only wanted back yyyy/MM/dd, but JBoss wanted to return the entire timestamp.

I found this last week and it solves the problem. Here is a link to the overall [example.](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/exchanging_data_with_xml_and)

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    // the desired format
    private String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";

    public String marshal(Date date) throws Exception {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(date);
    }

    public Date unmarshal(String dateString) throws Exception {
        return new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).parse(dateString);
    }
```